# How to add a collection of documents to a newly created document in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have built a messaging app using react and firebase. When a user creates a new group chat, a new document a new chat id (made randomly by Firebase) is created, with the date that the chat was created. The participants of the group chat are added to a new 'participants' collection which is added to the new chat document afterwards. Here is my code:

```
   db.collection('chats').add({ //add generates new chat document and id
            created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() // when new chat was created
        })
            .then((docRef) => { //docRef.id contains newly created chat Id
                console.log("docRef is" + docRef.id) // this works, and new chatId is created
                    db.collection("chats")
                    .doc(docRef.id) //this isn't working, firebase is creating a new document with new random id, instead of using the docRef.id created above which represents the new chat.
                    .collection("participants")
                    .doc(auth.currentUser.id)
                    .set(currentUser)
                   
                    db.collection("chats")
                    .doc(docRef.id) //not working
                    .collection("participants")
                    .doc(user.id)
                    .set(otherUser)

...
```

docRef.id works and is returned correctly as shown by the console.log. However, when I try to reference it in the following statements it doesn't work and Firebase creates a brand new document, instead of adding to the one I want.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong! Thanks.

Comment: Can you try running code in my answer and check if `console.log("New chat ID:" + newChatId)` runs more than once?

Comment: What happens if you do `docRef.collection("participants").doc(auth.currentUser.id).set(currentUser)` instead of `db.collection("chats").doc(docRef.id).collection("participants").doc(auth.currentUser.id).set(currentUser)`? Also, do you get any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine to me. Are you sure the same function isn't running again which is creating new chats? Also you are not awaiting those promises returned by `set()`. Try refactoring to this:

```
db.collection('chats').add({
  created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}).then(async (docRef) => {
  // async ^^

  const newChatId = docRef.id
  console.log("New chat ID:" + newChatId)

  const newChatRef = db.collection("chats").doc(docRef.id)

  await newChatRef.collection("participants").doc(auth.currentUser.id).set(currentUser)
  await newChatRef.collection("participants").doc(user.id).set(otherUser)
})
```

Addionally, if you are adding multiple documents once, try using [Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) so they all are either added or not if any one of them fails.

Comment: This solved it, thank you so much. I didn't realise that .set() returns a promise whereas .add() does not.

Comment: @bobby_belfast `add()` returns a promise too. You did handle it by using `.then()`.. I just used async await syntax for adding users part.

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense why the .add() worked but not the .set(). One thing I just noticed, in the code above you'll see that I am trying to create a new document for each participant with an ID that is the same as user IDs. I notice that firebase is not doing that, firebase is just randomly generating new IDs. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Ah it's because .add() always uses auto-generate ID, but .set() allows for a new one. Sorry, I'm new to Firebase.

Comment: @bobby_belfast if you want to specify ID yourself then use `set()`

Comment: .set() doesn't seem to be using custom ID though, it still seems to use firebase autogenerated? Is this correct: db.collection('chats').doc(newCustomIdHere).set()   ??

Comment: @bobby_belfast the code in your comment will add a new document with `newCustomIdHere` in chats collection. Where is that `newCustomIdHere` coming from ? Make sure it is defined other wise it will use random ID if undefined. The [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method: _"Get a DocumentReference for the document within the collection at the specified path. If no path is specified, an automatically-generated unique ID will be used for the returned DocumentReference."_